# add null end of string

Tags: c++, string, null, strtok

I have a string declared char sentence[100];
In a loop, I read different sentences from a txt file and I'm trying to do this:

```
sentence = strtok (sentencefromtxtfile," ,.-");
//seperating word by word in a loop
```

And I can do. but there is a little problem. Lets say the lenght of sentecenfromtxtfile is just 10. Example:

sentencefromtxtfile ="John" -> with NULL, it is 5 character. But strtok function cant notice the NULL ch. so my sentence variable is being like this:

```
John ÿ( ÕŒ•vÍ>È àı~øş( j (total 100 char)
```

so how can I fix that? I mean, can I adjust the length of the sentence ? cos it is fix and 100.. Anyway, sorry for my stupid english. I hope you guys got what I mean? thanks in advance..

Comment: `strtok` handles the null-terminator just fine. What does your code actually look like?

Comment: You shouldn't overwrite `sentence`, since that's the only pointer to the array that you have. Instead, use a new pointer, `char * p = strtok(sentence, "...");`

Answer (score 4):

You can prefill your buffer with `\0` characters before populating it by issuing:

```
char sentencefromtxtfile[100] = { 0 };
```

This should solve your problem, since all the characters `strtok()` leaves untouched will be `NUL`.

Comment: they didnt work. I wonder if there is a function like mid() like in the VB? u know; mid("hello",1,3)=>hel. then maybe i can cut the string using their length....

Comment: It can be achieved, but for this level of abstraction, you probably should use an `std::string` instead of a character array, as Daniel Daranas rightfully suggests.

Comment: Also, I mistakenly used `sentence` instead of `sentencefromtxtfile` in my original answer (we need to prefill the original buffer, not the pointer returned by `strtok()`). Maybe that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`char[100]` is an array of 100 char's, not a string. You may consider using `std::string`.